# How do I inject Db into Service classes when unit testing ServiceStack.OrmLite with NUnit?

Tags: nunit, inversion-of-control, ormlite-servicestack

I'm interested in writing unit tests (using NUnit) for some service classes created using ServiceStack, using the "New API" (inheriting from ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Service). The services' Db property is properly auto-wired when hosted in an ASP.NET application using AppHost, but I can't seem to figure out the proper technique when running outside of that environment. I see a variety of testing-related namespaces and classes in ServiceStack but can't find a clear example where a service's Db property is getting injected, as opposed to simply setting up a connection factory directly and then calling the various IDbConnection extension methods (Insert, Select, etc.).

I have tried having my test class inherit from ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Testing.TestBase and overriding its Configure method to register an IDbConnectionFactory (using ":memory:"), as well as setting `OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider = SqliteDialect.Provider;` in my TestFixtureSetUp, but I continue to get a NullReferenceException when calling my service methods (at at ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Service.get_Db()). It seems that the Funq container is not auto-wiring anything.

SQLite itself is properly set up, which I'm able to confirm with simpler unit tests that bypass my service classes and simply do direct IDbConnection calls.

What am I missing?

**Edit**

It appears that unit-testing ServiceStack services requires the existence of a host and a client, although it looks like there are ways to set this up to avoid the serialization cost (using the DirectServiceClient, as shown [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.IntegrationTests/Tests/WebServicesTests.cs)) -- though I haven't succeeded in getting that to work in my case. I managed to get this working using an AppHostHttpListenerBase approach (see [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/NewApiTodos.cs)) although it's more of an integration test than a unit one (and is accordingly slower).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [docs on Testing](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Testing) shows a couple of different approaches for injecting dependencies.

If you look at the implementation for the base [Service](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Service.cs#L69) it just creates the **Db** from the `IDbConnectionFactory`:

```
private IDbConnection db;
public virtual IDbConnection Db
{
    get { return db ?? (db = TryResolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().OpenDbConnection()); }
}
```

That it just resolves from the local or Global `IResolver` IOC container:

```
public static IResolver GlobalResolver { get; set; }

private IResolver resolver;
public virtual IResolver GetResolver()
{
    return resolver ?? GlobalResolver;
}

public virtual T TryResolve<T>()
{
    return this.GetResolver() == null
        ? default(T)
        : this.GetResolver().TryResolve<T>();
}
```

So to inject your own dependencies (when using Service base class) you just need to configure a `IAppHost` with your dependencies your services need which you can do with:

```
using (var appHost = new BasicAppHost {
    ConfigureContainer = c => {
        c.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(new ...);
    }
}.Init())
{
  //...    
}
```

Which you can then set on your service along with any of your own dependencies your service needs, e.g:

```
var service = appHost.ResolveService<MyService>();
```

Which will autowire all dependencies configured in your AppHost, you can also add your own adhoc test-specific dependencies via normal property access, e.g:

```
var service.MyDependency = new Mock<IMyDependency>().Object;
```

From then on you can just call and test your C# class methods as per usual:

```
var response = service.Get(new RequestDto { ... });
Assert.That(response.Result, Is.Equal("Expected Result from DB"));
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks! I had to convert one of my ExpectedExceptions back to the inner one (HttpError) from the wrapper (WebServiceException) but that makes sense given that I'm no longer going through a service client.